# $a^{\log_b(c)} = c^{\log_b(a)}$

Tags: logarithms, proof-writing

I'm not sure how to start.  My questions is how do you prove:

$$a^{\log_b(c)} = c^{\log_b(a)}$$ where $a,b,c > 0$.

Comment: Hint: take log on both sides

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Use that $$\log_b c=\frac{\log c}{\log b}$$

Here $\log$ is the natural logarithm.

Answer (score 0):

As $e^{\log_ea}=a$ and $\log_bm=\frac{\log m}{\log b}$

$$a^{\log_bc}=(e^{\log_ea})^{\log_bc}=e^{\log_ea \cdot \log_bc}=e^{\log_ec\cdot \log_ba}=(e^{\log_ec})^{\log_ba}=c^{\log_ba}$$

Comment: How do you calculate your third step to your fourth?

Comment: @user82627, As $$\log_bm=\frac{\log m}{\log b}, \log _ea\cdot \log_bc=\frac{\log a}{\log e}\cdot \frac{\log c}{\log b}=\frac{\log c}{\log e}\cdot \frac{\log a}{\log b}=\log_ec\cdot\log_ba  $$

Answer (score 0):

$$a^{\log_b(c)}=(b^{\log_b(a)})^{\log_b(c)}=b^{\log_b(a)\log_b(c)}$$
$$c^{\log_b(a)}=(b^{\log_b(c)})^{\log_b(a)}=b^{\log_b(c)\log_b(a)}$$